# Communication Between Browser and QGIS Server/QGIS API

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, web-service, rest, qgis-server

Suppose I have QGIS server up and running with some vector data. Now a user accesses this data from a webpage. Would it be possible in some ways for the user to send a request to the QGIS Server and make it do some Vector Geo-processing at the server side and return the results? (For example user sends a select query on a point layer. The Server will calculate the Convex Hull and return the WKT.)

As per the [QGIS website](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial),

> QGIS Server provides a web map service (WMS) using the same libraries
>   as the Quantum GIS (QGIS) desktop application.

If it is not possible at present, would it be possible to create something like a REST service(i got the term from ArcGIS REST API) which can hold communication between user and QGIS server? What are the difficulties in implementing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options:

1. run the operation directly in the browser with the ever-improving [Javascript Topology Suite](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts), which btw support the [ConvexHull](http://bjornharrtell.github.com/jsts/doc/api/symbols/jsts.algorithm.ConvexHull.html) operation you cite
2. other than using a WPS server you can also roll your own lightweight version which just runs on top of [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/JTSHome.htm), like [this one](http://unicolet.blogspot.it/2012/01/jts-processing-grails-servlet.html) I have coded some time ago.
3. as in 2, but with different technology: if you're feeling adventurous and want to be cool you could also use [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) (which for sure is more lightweight that the complete java stack required by my previous suggestion), as I hint in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/2818482)

Note that item 3 is essentially the same as 1, only running server-side instead of running in the browser

Comment: i loved option 2!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for a WPS Server. QGIS Server is a WMS&WFS Server but it does not handle WPS. If you're interested in adding WPS support to QGIS Server (programming yourself or supporting a programmer), contact the developer mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a snowplow to win a go-kart race. As underdark said, you are probably looking for a WPS server (several out there).

On the other hand, depending on your use case, you may be better of just writing a [thin layer (say python/django) on top of postgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28078/advice-on-a-generic-open-source-package-roadmap)